# Store a Timezone in a decimal

Tags: javascript, time

This may be a strange question, but I'm using a Decimal to store a timestamp with more than millisecond precision. For example:

1. The time of 00:01:15, would be 75 seconds / 216000 seconds in a day = 0.00034722222.
2. The date of "2014-01-01 ==> 41638 (days since 1900-01-01)
3. The datetime of "2014-01-01 00:01:15.12222" would be 41638.00034778805.

Is there any possible way at all to include the timezone (such as "-6") in this data type? I think the answer is no, but I was wondering if there might be any tricks to be able to store that amount in the decimal.

I don't think it's possible, and perhaps I'll need to use either a String or an Array of `[<datetime>, <timezone>]` to get past Javascript's millisecond precision (using a library such as Decimal.js for high precision decimals), but I was wondering what might be possible here.

The reason I'm using a decimal here to be able to store a time or date in a similar format and to be able to add them together for certain operations (such as how Excel or Google Sheets would store dates/times, as a number). But timezone complicates things quite a bit here.

Comment: Why do you need in decimal format, ? `unix` timestamps are more standard way of storing the timestamps

Comment: @CodeManiac how would you store the time "00:02:14", for example, to add a time to a date?

Comment: I think sharing how you plan to use the decimal will help find a solution.

Comment: standard way (IMO) is to store as `unix` timestamps and then parse `timestamp` using `Date` API and get desired attribute from it, in this case it time

Comment: why not just plain `new Date('2014-01-01 00:01:15.12222').getTime()`? You'll get a number (without timezone) that you can use for "add them together"

Comment: @YongQuan -- it's a tiny thing really, but I'm trying to get more than millisecond precision. In the above, you only get to `.122` and not `.12222`.

Comment: your solution lies in [performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) used in the High resolution time API. Unfortunately, this became an exploit for the miscreants. So most browsers now only provide 1millis precision rather than micros precision. And here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp

Comment: @RandyCasburn got it, yea I was trying that out a bit. Out of curiosity, do you know why an application like Excel or Google Sheets would store dates and such as numbers?

Comment: For the same reason most use the Epoch that is built into most DateTime programming interfaces. Math is easier. Most stick to Z time for all calculations and storage. Timezone is only relevant to the end user, on their system, at the time of the use of the data. That is, after all, why Locale exists. But hey, spread your butter your way. Have fun.